# How to choose the rows where the first occurrence of a value happens with groupby in pandas and also the first of the consequent occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'time': [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,9], 'taken': [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]})
```

This `df` is already order with respect to `id` & `time`.

I would like to keep only the rows where `taken` has value `1` by `id`, and if there are two (or more) consequent `1`s in the column `taken` to keep only the first of these.

My output `df` should like this:

```
  id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
4   1     5      1
6   2     7      1
8   2     9      1
```

**Second example**

To make the question a bit more clear, if the dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'time': [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,9], 'taken': [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]})
```

Then the output dataframe should look like this:

```
   id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
5   2     4      1
8   2     9      1
```

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a boolean mask by grouping by `id`, and then taking the values where `taken` is True but its shifted value is not True.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'time': [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,9], 'taken': [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'time': [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,9], 'taken': [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]}) 

df = df1  # First example.
>>> df[df.groupby('id')['taken'].shift().ne(True) & df['taken']]
   id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
4   1     5      1
6   2     7      1
8   2     9      1

df = df2  # Second example.
>>> df[df.groupby('id')['taken'].shift().ne(True) & df['taken']]
   id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
5   2     4      1
8   2     9      1
```

Comment: I think you don't need `transform`. Calling `shift` directly on groupby. It would be faster: `df.groupby('id')['taken'].shift().ne(True) & df.taken`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
taken_is_one = df.taken.eq(1)
df[taken_is_one & (~taken_is_one.shift(-1, fill_value=False) 
                | df.groupby('id').id.shift(1).isna())]

   id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
5   2     4      1
8   2     9      1
```

---

Where with:

```
~taken_is_one.shift(-1, fill_value=False)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
```

We will have `True` only if the next value in `taken` was not a 1, hence by combining with a `&` we can index on both conditions being `True`.

Comment: this wont give the desiring result if the data frame looks like this `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'time': [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,9], 'taken': [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]})` I think a groupby `id` is needed

Comment: Hmmm true, let me change this @quant

Comment: Check now @quant

Comment: still, in the second dataframe that I provided, the output is different than what it should :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with several mask. First check where the value is 1 in taken. Then you need to check either: still the same id and difference with the previous row is not 0 or not same idea:

```
print (df[df.taken.eq(1) & (df.id.diff().eq(0) & df.taken.diff().ne(0) | df.id.diff().ne(0))])
   id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
4   1     5      1
6   2     7      1
8   2     9      1
```

Comment: I only chose Alexander's answer, because it is more generic, in the sense that it works even if `id` column is a `string`. But thank you very much for your time and effort as well :)

Comment: @quant makes sense, and it is also safer if the id is not well ordered :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['taken'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0)) & df['taken'].eq(1)]
```

or

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['taken'].diff().ne(0) & df['taken'].eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
   id  time  taken
1   1     2      1
4   1     5      1
6   2     7      1
8   2     9      1
```